# How to wrap Amplifys Authenticator widget a parent widget to achieve a background image?

Tags: flutter, aws-amplify

I'm building a Windows and a Web app using Flutter and Amplify. The users have to authenticate themselves before moving to the home page. My problem is that the Authentication page has a white background with the AWS Authenticator widget in the center.

How can I wrap the Authenticator widget in another widget to achieve a background image?

My code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Authenticator(
      child: MaterialApp(
        scrollBehavior: const MaterialScrollBehavior().copyWith(
          dragDevices: {
            PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
            PointerDeviceKind.touch,
            PointerDeviceKind.stylus,
            PointerDeviceKind.unknown,
            PointerDeviceKind.trackpad
          },
        ),
        builder: Authenticator.builder(),
        home: Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            Platform platform = Platform();
            AWSManager().init();
            return platform.home;
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem following this answer

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/issues/2920